# EmberJS, load vendor folder after templates fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I put `$(window).on(function(){...});` in the JS file.
I put a  tag right before  tag close.
I imported JS files in ember-cli-build.js

I tried multiple ways to have the js file executed after the templates fully loaded, but it still failed.

I deployed the web application to http://purple-cows.surge.sh/.
What I wanted to accomplish is that, in Mobile version, the $('#sidebar') has `inactive` class.

Could anyone explain the proper way to load external JS files for Ember application?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such event in ember "templates fully loaded". Templates can be re-rendered during app work many times. I'm not sure what do you need, but:

1. If you need to handle 'resize' event and apply some class to the whole page, you may write your js-code in app/index.html in the end of body tag (or put your js-file in public/assets and include it from app/index.html).
2. If you need to do something *after render*, you should [create a component](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/) for sidebar and use `didInsertElement` hook of that component.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the concepts here. I think I should create a component for it.